# reduxForm 7.0.4 Importing a <Field> tag inside a string value from a database and outputting it onto the UI

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to render `<Field>` tags inside a string from a database fetch call to the UI. But when I run the code it renders the `<Field>` tags as a string instead of Redux Form elements.

Here's the key/value from the database object I'm fetching:

```
ConditionDescription: "Overall, (client) demonstrated a consistent performance on the WAIS-IV and received a Full-Scale IQ (FSIQ) score of <Field
name='wais-iv-fsiq-score' type='text' component='input'/> (<Field name='wais-iv-fsiq-percentile' type='text' component='input'/> percentile), which falls within in the <Field name='wais-iv-fsiq-range' type='text' component='input'/> range of functioning."
```

Here's my JSX code:

```
{t.IndexConditions.map(t => (
    <div key={t.Id}>
        <div className="flex test__list">
            <MaterialIcon icon="arrow_right" />
            <p>{t.ConditionDescription}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

P.S. I tried using a parser package `<p>{ReactHTMLParser(t.ConditionDescription)}</p>` and I got an error - Unknown prop "component" on `<field>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function that generates those Fields to you based on your data. 
For native html tags you could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it is not recommended.

You could try something like:

```js
{t.IndexConditions.map(t => (
    <div key={t.Id}>
        <div className="flex test__list">
            <MaterialIcon icon="arrow_right" />
            {t.fieldsList.length > 0 && t.fieldsList.map(field => (
              <div>
                <Field name={field.name} type={field.type} component={field.component} /> 
                {field.label} 
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

Edited: You are getting the `Unknown prop "component"` because `<Field>` is not a native html tag